# Как перенаправить пользователя если не прошел валидацию Laravel Jetstream

Tags: laravel

Я добавил дополнительное условие проверки почты. Если она входит в массив запрещенных почт, то хочу просто направить пользователя без никаких сообщений обратно на главную страницу. Создал EmailRule в котором выполняю проверку. В функцию зоздания пользователя добавил редирект, но получаю такую ошибку:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an
> instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of
> Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given, called in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\fortify\src\Http\Controllers\RegisteredUserController.php
> on line 56

```
<?php

namespace App\Actions\Fortify;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\CreatesNewUsers;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream;
use App\Rules\EmailRule;

class CreateNewUser implements CreatesNewUsers
{
    use PasswordValidationRules;


    /**
     * Validate and create a newly registered user.
     *
     * @param  array  $input
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    public function create(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
            'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature() ? ['required', 'accepted'] : '',
        ])->validate();

        $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'email' => [new EmailRule()]
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/');
        } 

        $user =  User::create([
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Как используете метод покажите

Answer (score 0):

Валидации входных параметров нужна для проверки входных параметров. Перенаправление должно быть в контроллере.
Подобный вопрос уже был ранее здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177044/laravel-5-4-redirection-to-custom-url-after-login